# Rails-customize devise validation when user sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I have a table

```
User(id,email,encrypted_password,status)  status default:false
```

I already use gem devise for sign in,sign up.When user sign in, I want only users with status(=true) can log in and alert message "This user inactive for user(status=false).
How can I customize validate status(=true) for only sign in case

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise provides hook for this. Add the following method in your `User` model.

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && status
end
```

For a more detailed reference, look at this guide
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in

Comment: I tested your code,I realize that user with status true or false can sign in successful. log debug :--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
action: new
controller: sessions
user: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters {}

Comment: PS.Route log:new_user_session_path  GET  /users/sign_in(.:format)  sessions#new
user_session_path  POST  /users/sign_in(.:format)  sessions#create.

Comment: Sorry, I was somehow assuming that you were using STI. For plain devise setup, you just need the above mentioned hook.